# Where on the filesytem could a user find the Unity scope files?

Tags: unity, application-development, filesystem, scopes

I am wanting to find the Unity scope folder so that I can study how the scopes are set up and programmed. Where on the filesytem could I find the Unity scope files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation on the Unity scope API can be found [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/lenses-and-scopes/).  That information should be current for 13.04, but there are some changes coming in 13.10 which merge the concepts of lenses and scopes.

Unity discovers its lenses and scopes by looking for files under `/usr/share/unity/lenses` (or `/usr/share/unity/scopes` for 13.10) with a suffix of `.lens` or `.scope`.

These files are similar to [desktop entry](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) files, but instead of specifying a command to execute, they specify a D-Bus endpoint to use to talk to the lens or scope through the `DBusName` and `DBusPath` keys.

If the scope or lens is not running when the shell tries to communicate with it, the D-Bus daemon will activate it.  This is done by scanning `/usr/share/dbus-1/services` for a `.service` file whose `Name` key matches the desired bus name, and running the command in the `Exec` key.  So it is not too difficult to discover what program implements a particular scope with a simple `grep` command.

If you are interested in writing a scope of your own, I would suggest looking at the documentation in the first link.  But keep in mind that you may have to adjust your scope a bit when 13.10 comes out.

Comment: Thank you for are detailed and clear answer. This is the best answer I have ever received on the Internet.

Comment: This question is referenced on developer.ubuntu.com (http://developer.ubuntu.com/scopes/cookbook/) so it would be nice if the answer was updated now that 13.04 is history and we're getting closer to the next LTS.

Comment: It is still valid for the scopes framework being used by Unity 7.  We're still working out the details for the new framework, so it's a bit premature to update the question just yet.